# How to retrieve stash account of a nomination pool creator?

Tags: polkadot-js

How to retrieve stash account of a nomination pool creator? for e.g. below

https://polkadot.subscan.io/nomination_pool/1?tab=member

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way is to use subscan API, which runs its own custom indexer to get the data.

```
POST: https://polkadot.webapi.subscan.io/api/scan/nomination_pool/pool

{"pool_id":1}
```

The API calls made on the [subscan nom pools UI](https://polkadot.subscan.io/nomination_pool/1?tab=member)

Other subscan APIs can be accessed [here](https://support.subscan.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is a more efficient/better method.
The workaround I found is to first query  `bondedPools`:

```js
const bondedPool = await api.query.nominationPools.bondedPools(1);
```

Here you can get the points (bondedPool.points), e.g: 3,168,542,829,169,032

Now similar as you suggested, fetch all entries of `api.query.staking.ledger.entries()` which is the map from all "controller" accounts to the info regarding the staking.
And use the number of points to compare with the `active` field from the ledgers entries and if matches you have the stash account there.

[image]